# How to build the chromium with the tarball

Tags: chromium, gyp

I got the chromium tarball from the http://gsdview.appspot.com/chromium-browser-official.
But it can't use `gyp_chromium` to configure the chromium project, the error message as following:

```
Updating projects from gyp files...
gyp: Could not automatically locate src directory.  This isa temporary     
   Chromium feature that will be removed.  Use--depth as a workaround.
```

Seems it couldn't follow the steps as http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code and I can't find another data on google.

Is there anyone can give a clue to compile the chromium with the tarball?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the some error message, but using gyp_chromium like this got me to another step:

```
./build/gyp_chromium --toplevel-dir=src/  --depth .
```

gyp_chromium has some more options which provide more verbose output and might help in case of any further problems.